# Expect typescript tsc to throw error but none was thrown

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In the IDE used to edit the typescript code, there is a warning in checkApp.ts stating:

```
Argument type { someWrongParams: any } is not assignable to parameter type AddAppToListParams.
```

However when I run `tsc` there's no error being thrown. How do I make an error show up when running `tsc`.

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "module": "ES6",
    "target": "ES6"
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
],
"include": [
    "./src/**/*"
]}
```

Code
checkApp.ts

```
interface CheckAppParams {
    appId: string;
}

export default (app: any) => async (requestParams: CheckAppParams): Promise<any> => {
    const { appId } = requestParams;
    await app.tasks.addAppToList({ someWrongParams: appId });
};
```

addAppToList.ts

```
interface AddAppToListParams {
    appId: string;
}

export default (app: any) => async (requestParams: AddAppToListParams): Promise<any> => {
    const { appId } = requestParams;
    app.list.push(appId);
};
```

tasks.ts

```
import checkApp from './checkApp';
import addAppToList from './addAppToList';

export default (app: any) => async (): Promise<any> => {
    app.tasks = {
        addAppToList: addAppToList(app),
        checkApp: checkApp(app),
    };
};
```

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities for why this happens. Maybe your ide compiler settings are different from when you build, maybe they are using different versions. It's hard to say without more info, such as code, tsconfig and the way you actually build

Comment: have added tsconfig.json .. IDE (Intellij) is showing only a warning and not an error I suspect I need to add some config to change the warning into an error

Comment: After adding tsconfig tsc still doesn't show any error? Also would be helpful if you'll add actual code...

Comment: yup after adding tsconfig its still only showing a warning in IDE but not throwing an error when running tsc .. have added code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want tsc to throw an error you can define `app` as an `interface` and refer it instead of `any`, otherwise the typescript compiler will not know what it is.

Defining your app as an interface will allow the compiler to recognize the error:

```
export interface App {
  tasks: {
    addAppToList: (requestParams: AddAppToListParams) => Promise<any>;
    checkApp: (requestParams: CheckAppParams) => Promise<any>;
  };
  list: any; // you can make it whatever it needs to be.
}
```

The viability of such an `interface` depends on your use of the `app`. 
The above interface is just an example, it can be anything you need it to be.

**Alternatively** You can add a prebuild hook to your `package.json` to do a lint check before you run `tsc` to check for the warnings your IDE throws and prevent tsc from running. You'll have to use the same linter rules your IDE uses, but it'll allow you to add more stringent checks to your build than only the default typescript ruleset defined in your `tsconfig.json`

So instead of `tsc` use `npm run build` from wherever you previously ran `tsc`

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "do your lint checks here with can throw errors if you want",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

It is correct for `tsc` to not report an error when compiling *the code you show in the question*. Your expectation is incorrect.

In `checkApp.ts` you explicitly define the parameter of the exported function as `(app: any)`. Therefore inside the function, `app.tasks` is also of type `any` and `app.tasks.addAppToList` is also of type `any` and the compiler will let you do whatever you want with it. There's no reason for the compiler to give an error when you do `app.tasks.addAppToList({ someWrongParams: appId });`.

As for why your IDE flags an error, there's isn't enough information in the question to explain that. Maybe you modified your code for pasting here in a way that did not preserve critical information. Maybe your IDE is operating on different files than those you pass to the compiler. (I'd like to say it never happened to me, but sometimes on large refactors, I got distracted, lost track of the plot, and managed to get my wires crossed for a bit.) Actually, the error message you show does hint to a difference between the code your IDE is working with, and the code you show in the question. The code in the question is passing an argument of type: `{ someWrongParams: string }` but the error message from the IDE complains about a parameter of type `{ someWrongParams: any }`.